# Does vcpkg still work on macOS since new M series laptops?

Tags: c++, apple-m1, qmake, vcpkg, fmt

While using QtCretor I put together the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/core.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout  << "starting..." << endl;

    std::string s = fmt::format("The answer is {}.", 42);

    return 0;
}
```

```
CONFIG -= debug_and_release debug_and_release_target

CONFIG += c++17

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
     MODE = debug
     d = d
} else {

}

INCLUDEPATH += $$(VCPKG)/include
     LIBS += -L$$(VCPKG)/$${MODE}/lib
     LIBS += -lfmt$${d}

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \

HEADERS += \
```

Where I set

```
export VCPKG=~/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx
```

Installed `fmt` with `vcpkg` on MacBook Air M1. But then got:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../Frameworks -Wl,-rpath,/Users/user/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/lib -o project.app/Contents/MacOS/project main.o   -F/Users/user/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/lib -L/Users/user/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/debug/lib -lfmtd -framework QtGui -framework AppKit -framework Metal -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL   
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/user/vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx/debug/lib/libfmtd.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "fmt::v9::vformat(fmt::v9::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v9::basic_format_args<fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [project.app/Contents/MacOS/project] Error 1
17:25:55: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 clang 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.15.2 clang 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

What should I do?

Comment: I do not see anything which triggers VCPKG to download dependencies. You need ask VCPKG to download respective version of library. Note also you are building your program for x86_64 not for ARM64, so maybe you ask VCPKG to download ARM64 version of library, but you build for x64 and run under Rosetta.

Comment: I run `vcpkg install fmt` which installed it on `vcpkg/installed/arm64-osx`, I think. That is the respective version of the library, isn't?

Comment: Yes but logs from building application says you are building to `x86_64`! So you have to change configuration in QtCreator to enforce ARM or better universal executable (You need universal library in such case).

Comment: How to proceed in order to get that universal executable and universal library?

Comment: `qmake ~/src/myapp QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS=arm64` https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding (as pointed by Marek_R)

```
QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS = arm64
```

to .pro seems to solve the problem.

Still wondering why that's not the default behavior though.

Comment: Because qmake has be deprecated and was developed before M1 was a mainstream thing? Also your qmake was probably build for `x64_x86` and not `arm64`? qmake defaults to the mkspec it was build with.